# Facebook SDK 3.1 presentShareDialogModally fails

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to test out the new built-in share "sheet" for Facebook on iOS 6 but when I run the sample code it doesn't show the sheet. Instead it posts a status for me without showing what it's going to post first. Also I thought Facebook didn't allow you to put words in the user's mouth anymore? The console prints this error: HelloFacebookSample Error: HTTP status code: 400

I have XCode 4.5 and iOS simulator 6.0 and Facebook SDK 3.1

I'm following this:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you set up the Facebook account on the device/simulator (under Settings->Facebook)?

The native sheet dialogs are only presented when the app is running on ios 6 AND the user is authenticated through the ios 6 Facebook account. Otherwise, the handler does report that error and the `presentShareDialogModallyFrom` returns "NO". Also, the `FBNativeDialogResult result` in the handler will equal `FBNativeDialogResultError`.

Comment: That was it thanks! Seems obvious now but the tutorial didn't list it as a step, and the example didn't handle that case. Does every user have to go in to their settings or can I make my app change the settings if they approve?

Comment: what if the user has not configured facebook like that , for example a  family which share an iPad? is there an alternative method equivalent to the previous facebook dialog:@"stream.publish" andParams: andDelegate

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some of the required frameworks:

AdSupport.framework

Account.framework

Social.framework

```
BOOL displayedNativeDialog =
[FBNativeDialogs
 presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
 initialText:self.shareText
 image:nil
 url:nil
 handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         /* handle failure */
         NSLog(@"error:%@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
     } else {
         if (result == FBNativeDialogResultSucceeded) {
             /* handle success */
             NSLog(@"handle success");
         } else {
             /* handle user cancel */
             NSLog(@"user cancel");
         }
     }
 }];
if (!displayedNativeDialog) {
    /* handle fallback to native dialog  */
}
```

Comment: Make sure you device/simulator is iOS 6.0

Comment: Here's what I get: HelloFacebookSample[2470:19a03] error:Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 7.)" UserInfo=0x94954d0 {com.facebook.sdk:NativeDialogReasonKey=NativeDialogInvalidForSession}, The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 7.)

Comment: Did you setup your facebook AppID in the plist?https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/errorcodes/

Comment: It's already there. All I did was download the sample code project from developers.facebook.com and run it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not opening sessions using deprecated methods (ie.openActiveSessionWithPermissions instead of the newer openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions/openActiveSessionWithWritePermissions) or the facebook sdk won't use native facebook integration (ie. native dialogs)